# Django way to filter and select the last record for each month by ids in a time series?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a timeseries data stored in postgres. I would like to see the last recorded views for each month given a video id.

```
VideoID  |   created   |  views
  1        2015-01-01      5
  2        2015-01-01      5
  1        2015-01-15      20
  1        2015-01-28      30
  2        2015-02-01      40
  1        2015-02-01      50
  1        2015-02-26      60  
  1        2015-03-05      100
```

Given the model

```
from django.db import models

class Video(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()

class VideosStats(models.Model):
    video_id = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    views = models.IntegerField()
```

I understand there are similar SQL questions but I am wondering if in django, you can accomplish this effect. Desired output:

Video id 1
[{'created': 2015-01-28, 'views': 30}, {'created': 2015-02-26, 'views': 60}, {'created': 2015-03-05, 'views': 100}]

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: If you wanted a raw sql query posting the table structure is the right thing to do but you are asking for an orm query so shouldn't you be posting models?

Comment: the table is reflective of the model @e4c5 and posting the table helps you understand how the data is structured. it is a better visual in my opinion. I haven't tried anything because I'm assuming it isn't possible.

Comment: also curious as to why this got down voted

Comment: if you want us to translate your table to a model, you have another think coming.

Comment: The second down vote is from me reasons are in my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given a year, you can execute an extra/extract filter on your queryset to give you the the latest record for each month for each video.

```
the_year = 2016 # the year you want
queryset = VideoStats.filter(created__year=the_year)
queryset = queryset.extra(select={'month': "EXTRACT(month from created)"}).values('month').annotate(Max('views')).order_by('month')
```